# Selinux: how to allow an application to access a device

Tags: android, selinux

I m working on the integration of a new HW device in an Android phone.
The kernel driver is working correctly, already tested with shell test scripts.

Now I would like to allow an application to open the device and communicate with it.
It works well when I disable the enforcing mode thanks to "setenforce 0" command, requiring root priviledge.
But I would like to modify the selinux files to allow such access without such modification.

When I launch the apk, I have the following error message:

```
denied { setattr } for name="device_name" dev="tmpfs" ino=11979 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:my_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
```

I guess the scontext is not correct. I have a specific context (my_dev_context) allowed to access to my_device.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try audit2allow.  It takes in your log and spits out the correct allow statements you need.

You're in security context "shell" because you're using adb shell.